# EPERM, operation not permitted

Tags: android, compiler-errors, titanium, appcelerator

I am using titanium and genymotion as android emulator. I am getting the following error:-

[ERROR] Error while firing "post-execute" event
[ERROR] Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Users\sudatta.titanium\analytics_session.json'
    at fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
    at fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:978:15)
    at c:\Users\sudatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\analytics.js:192:7
    at c:\Users\sudatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js
    at done (c:\Users\sudatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\lib\as
    at c:\Users\sudatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js
    at c:\Users\sudatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js
    at c:\Users\sudatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\analytics.js:113:5
    at getOSInfo (c:\Users\sudatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\environ.js:205:3

### at async.parallel.osinfo (c:\Users\sudatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\anal

```
at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\cli\hooks\run.js:353:13
at ADB.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:563:6)
at conn.exec.bufferUntilClose (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js
at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:251
at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

### at _stream_readable.js:944:16

```
at Connection.exec (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:248:9)
at ADB.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:486:9)
at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:171
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
```

### at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)

```
at Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:708:33)
at Connection.exec (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:119:9)
at ADB.shell (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:482:7)
at ADB.getPid (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:552:7)
at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\cli\hooks\run.js:343:15
at async.whilst (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:619:13)
at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\cli\hooks\run.js:340:15
```

### at conn.exec.bufferUntilClose (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js

```
at Connection.exec (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:248:9)
at ADB.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:486:9)
at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:171
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
```

### at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)

```
at Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:708:33)
at Connection.exec (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:119:9)
at ADB.shell (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:482:7)
at ADB.startApp (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:580:7)
at startApp (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\cli\hooks\run.js:334:12)
at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\cli\hooks\run.js:365:9
at iterate (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:134:13)
at async.eachSeries (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:150:9)
```

I have checked a few articles regarding the same which talks about genymotion bug, but my error does not seem to be relevant. Anyone has any idea why suddenly this error started to appear. 
I have the permission for the file analytics_session.json.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should end task Nodejs, and try building again. This happens because the EventIO is still attached to the earlier build process.

Comment: Exactly. On Windows, terminate Node.exe process and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write a file you don't have write permission to.  SInce you seem to have a file handle, you must have opened it in read mode instead of write.

Comment: I am really clueless here. Is it analytics_session.json file?? How should I change the permission?? @GabeSechan

Comment: Yes, I think so.  WHen you open a file, you specify a mode-  read, write, readwrite, append, etc.  You specified read and needed to specify write or readwrite.

Comment: Oh sorry, what i meant was that, i understand read write permission. I have full permission for the file. Can there be any other problem. @GabeSechan

Comment: But when you open it do you open it in write mode?  That's different than having permissions.  Permissions are an OS level thing.  Mode is something that happens with an individual file handle.